Expo push token notification not sending in production on server
I have a problem sending the expo token in production.
I use the following dependencies
"expo": "^51.0.11"
"expo-notifications": "~0.28.7",
"expo-permissions": "^14.4.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.2"

In development, everything works correctly, sending the token, saving the token linked to the user as well as sending notifications.
Sending notifications also works in production but for some reason, I cannot send the request to store the push token in production.
The server logs show no requests received on the production application.
In development, the request is received and returns 201 for a created token and 204 if the token already exists.
When the application starts, I look to see if a token is present in the user state, to decide whether or not I trigger the notification process.
URLAPI looks like this and is called from expo environment variables which works fine
URLAPI = "https://myendpointapi.com"

import * as React from "react";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import {Notification, Subscription} from "expo-notifications";
import {Platform} from "react-native";
import * as Device from "expo-device";
import {URLAPI} from "../utils/Constantes";
import useGlobal from "./useGlobal";
import {getDeviceType} from "../utils/Functions";
import axios from "axios";
import showToastMessage from "../components/toasts/Toast";
import Constants from "expo-constants";


const NotificationContext = () => {

    const user = useGlobal(state => state.user)
    const access = useGlobal(state=> state.access)
    const autenticathed = useGlobal(state => state.authenticated)

    const EnregistrementPushToken = async (token: any) => {
        const device = await getDeviceType()
        const data = {
            token_push_notification: token,
            device_name: Device.deviceName,
            application_name: "myapplicationname",
            device_type: device,
            systeme_exploitation: Platform.OS
        }
        const body = JSON.stringify(data)
        const config = {
            credentials: "include",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'Authorization': `JWT ${access}`,
                'Referer': URLAPI
            }
        };

        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${URLAPI}/myendpoint`, body, config)
        } catch (err: any) {
            showToastMessage(
                'error',
                `Oups ${user.prenom}`,
                `${err.response.data.detail}`
            )
        }
    }

    // Notifications
    const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = React.useState<string>('');
    const [notification, setNotification] = React.useState<Notification | null>(null);
    const notificationListener = React.useRef<Subscription | null>(null);
    const responseListener = React.useRef<Subscription | null>(null);

    async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync(): Promise<string> {
        let token = '';

        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
                name: 'default',
                importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
                vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
                lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
            });
        }

        if (Device.isDevice) {
            if (Object.keys(user).length !== 0) {
                const {status: existingStatus} = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
                let finalStatus = existingStatus;
                // si permission refusée dans les reglage de l'app
                if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
                    const {status} = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
                    finalStatus = status;
                }
                // si le status est accordé
                if (finalStatus === 'granted') {
                    // recuperation du token si notification user ok
                    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync(
                        {projectId: Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.eas?.projectId}
                    )).data;
                    if (autenticathed && Object.keys(user).length !== 0) {
                        // si l'utilisateur est authentifié et qu'il n'a pas de token
                        if (user.push_token_notification.length === 0) {
                            await EnregistrementPushToken(token)
                        } else {
                            const tokenFound = user.push_token_notification.some((obj: any) => obj === token);
                            if (!tokenFound) {
                                // si le token détecté n'est pas présent dans les tokens user présent, on enregistre le nouveau token
                                await EnregistrementPushToken(token)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return token;
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then((token) => setExpoPushToken(token));

        notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notif) => {
            setNotification(notif);
        });

        responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
            // console.log(response.notification.request.content.data);
        });

        return () => {
            if (notificationListener.current) {
                Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
            }

            if (responseListener.current) {
                Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
            }
        };
    }, [user]);

    return null

}

export default NotificationContext;

I then integrate the context into my authenticated layout
function RootNavigator() {

    const user = useGlobal(state => state.user)
    const isAuthenticated = useGlobal(state => state.authenticated)
    const followers = useGlobal(state => state.followers)
    const followings = useGlobal(state => state.followings)

    if (isAuthenticated && user.length !== 0) {
        return (
            <>
                <NotificationContext />
                <UserAuthenticateNavigator
                    user={user}
                    followers={followers}
                    followings={followings}
                />
            </>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Group>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Connexion" component={Connexion} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Etape 1" component={EtapeOne} options={{
                        headerShown: true,
                        header: () => <CustomHeaderNavigation/>
                    }}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Etape 2" component={EtapeTwo} options={{
                        headerShown: true,
                        header: () => <CustomHeaderNavigation/>
                    }}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Validation" component={Validation} options={{
                        headerShown: true,
                        header: () => <CustomHeaderNavigation/>
                    }}/>
                </Stack.Group>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        )
    }
}

Do you have any idea why my request is not being sent to production?
The whole process happening after works. Other production requests also work correctly.
Thanks for help
